# How to Disable the Future Date Entries in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I need to disable future dates on DateTimePicker Calender.(i.e) today's date is 27 Jun in the prefilled calender, then all dates start from 28 Jun should be disabled (i.e All future dates should be shown disable)and similarly all the past date entries should be enabled when user see calender element of DatePicker. Am using bootstrap library.

Please advice. Thanks in Advance
I am here by Pasting my HTML code:

> HTML Code:

```
 <div style="border:0;box-shadow:none;background:none;width:100px;padding:0;height:14px;text-align:center;" (click)="onStartEdit(d)">
                                                <img src="../../assets/images/icons/editicon.png" alt="edit" style="cursor:pointer;"> {{d.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                                            </div>
                                            <div *ngIf="datePickers[d.state]" id="startPicker" style="width: auto;">
                                                <datepicker name="datePickerEdit" [(ngModel)]="datePickerEdit" [showWeeks]="false" (selectionDone)="onEditDate(d,$event,edit_entry)" [dateDisabled]="dateDisabled"></datepicker>
                                                <div class="pickerBtns">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success  pull-right" (click)="onClose(d)">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                            </div>
```

with this {{d.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}, the date gets prefilled in the HTML. So based on this date, the future dates must b disabled and previous dates must b enabled.

> TypeScript:

```
public dateDisabled: {date: Date, mode: string}[];
public tomorrow: Date;
onStartEdit(d:any) {
  this.datePickers[d.state] = true;
  this.datePickerEdit = d.date;
}
onClose(d:any){
 this.datePickers[d.state] = false; 
}
public disableTomorrow(): void {
    this.dateDisabled = [{date: this.tomorrow, mode: 'day'}];
  }
```

Comment: You didn't even state what datepicker library you are using, how do you expect someone to help you?

Comment: am using bootstrap library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the maxDate property to new Date(), and it will work for you.
example : 
**this.datepickerOptions = new DatePickerOptions({
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            maxDate: new Date()
        });**
then set options property of ng2-datepicker :

```
<ng2-datepicker class="DatePicker" name="fromDate" [options]="datepickerOptions"></ng2-datepicker>
```

Comment: @MusheerAiman you need to use ng2-datepicker(ngx-datepicker), it will work fine, I consumed it in one of my projects.

Comment: <ng2-datepicker [(ngModel)]="startDate" [showWeeks]="true" (selectionDone)="onSelectionDone($event)"></ng2-datepicker>

Comment: you also need to provide [options]="datepickerOptions", and set datepickerOptions in TS file  : this.datepickerOptions = new DatePickerOptions({ format: 'DD-MM-YYYY', maxDate: new Date() });

Comment: @MohitJain: as dates are prefilled, so can u guide how to take that prefilled date

Comment: @MohitJain can you share any plunker.

Comment: @MohitJain link please

Comment: @MusheerAiman please check below example 
https://plnkr.co/edit/VIEUjbfYJPpREEWjy8Yq?p=preview

Comment: @MohitJain it's right but problem is when we select any previous date ex:26/06/2017 the future dates from 26th on wards should also be disabled.